# Proof Check: $4x^2+3x+17$ is continuous by using a $\epsilon$, $\delta$ Argument

Tags: calculus, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Can anyone double check my following epsilon delta proof.

I want to prove that the following function is continuous with an Epsilon Delta Argument.
$$ f: x \in \mathbb R \mapsto (4x^2+3x+17) \in \mathbb R $$

So I started with
$$\left\lvert f(x)-f(y) \right\rvert =$$
$$= \left\lvert (4x^2+3x+17) - (4y^2+3y+17) \right\rvert$$
$$= \left\lvert (4x^2+3x)-(4y^2+3y) \right\rvert$$
$$= 3\left\lvert (4x^2+x)-(4y^2+y) \right\rvert$$
$$= 3\left\lvert (\frac {4}{3}x^2+x)-(\frac {4}{3}4y^2+y) \right\rvert $$
$$= 3\left\lvert \frac {4}{3}x^2 - \frac {4}{3}y^2 + x-y \right\rvert$$
$$= 3\left\lvert \frac {4}{3}x^2 - \frac {4}{3}y^2 + x-y \right\rvert$$
(Triangel inequality)

$$\le 3 \left(\left\lvert \frac {4}{3}x^2 - \frac {4}{3}y^2 \right\rvert + \left\lvert x-y \right\rvert \right)$$

Note that $\delta \le 1$

$$\le 3 \left(\frac {4}{3}\left\lvert x^2 - y^2 \right\rvert + \delta \right)$$

$$= 3 \left(\frac {4}{3}\left\lvert (x - y) \right\rvert\left\lvert (x +y) \right\rvert + \delta \right)$$

$\delta \le 1$
$$\le 3 \left(\frac {4}{3}\left\lvert x + y \right\rvert \delta + \delta \right)$$
Adding zero in form of y - y
$$= 3 \left(\frac {4}{3}\left\lvert x + y - y + y \right\rvert \delta + \delta \right)$$
$$= 3 \left(\frac {4}{3}\left\lvert x - y + 2y \right\rvert \delta + \delta \right)$$
Triangel inequality
$$\le 3 \left(\frac {4}{3}(\left\lvert x - y \right\rvert +\left\lvert 2y \right\rvert) \delta + \delta \right)$$
Note that $\delta \le 1$

$$\le 3 \left(\frac {4}{3}(\delta +\left\lvert 2y \right\rvert) \delta + \delta \right)$$
$$= 4\delta^2+4\left\lvert 2y \right\rvert \delta + 3\delta $$
$$= \delta(4\delta+4\left\lvert 2y \right\rvert + 3) $$
Note that $\delta \le 1$
$$\le \delta(4 +4\left\lvert 2y \right\rvert + 3) $$
$$\le \delta(\left\lvert 8y \right\rvert + 7) = \epsilon$$
Therefore $$\delta = \frac {\epsilon}{(\left\lvert 8y \right\rvert + 7)} \;\; with \; \delta \le1$$

Thanks in advance for the help, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: There are so many errors here.. errors or typo

Comment: As I was typing this comment you corrected your error of $(M_x + N_x) - (M_y + N_y) \ne (M_x + M_y)-(N_x-N_y)$ to $(M_x+N_x)-(M_y+N_y) = (M_x - M_y) -(N_x-N_y)$.  But now you have an error $|a^2 - b^2| \ne |a-b||a-b|$.   $|a^2 - b^2| = |a+b||a-b|$.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you! Those are all typos, I don't know why I have so many errors in my latex code, but on the proof on my paper it is correct *facepalm*  I am so sorry.

Comment: Your final line is that $\delta$ is expressed in terms of the variable $y$.  That is an absolute and unresolvable no-no.

Comment: @fleablood Why is that a problem? (I am a student so.....)

Comment: @fleablood his $y$ is (something like) $x+\delta$, so maybe with some modifications between the last two lines it's fixable?

Comment: "Why is that a problem?" Because to choice $y$ so that $|x-y| < \delta$ you have to know what $\delta$ is first.  If $\delta = $something to do with $y$ you have to know $y$ first which is circular; you have to know what $y$ is before you can choose it.  @BenjaminWang "his y is (something like) x+δ, so maybe with some modifications between the last two lines it's fixable? " Maybe.  Probably. Conventionally we don't do $\delta$ dependent on $x$ but.... off hand that will prove it is continuous at *that* $x$ but as $x$ is arbitrary that could be acceptable... I think.

Comment: @fleablood But look for example at this epsilon delta proof for $x^3$:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378786/proof-that-fx-x3-is-continuous
Here delta is also dependend on y (or c in the other post)

Comment: $|2y| < 2|x| + 2\delta$ so $\delta(8|x| + 4\delta + 7)\le (8|x|+ 4)\delta +7$ ought to do it.  I thing.  But I'm a bit fussy about saying "Therefore $\delta = ....$"  ... that's not really the logic of the proof.  Better to say "therefore of we  choose a $\delta$ so that $0 < \delta \le \min(..., 1)$ that will be a valid choice and our result will follow" or something like that.

Comment: @fleablood I agree with you on that part. But per Definition I only need to proof that there *exists* a $\delta$. Isn't it okay then?

Comment: @fleablood So basically Therefore if we choose delta like _____ then follows abs(f(x)-f(y))< $\epsilon$. That would do it in your opinion, right @fleablood?

Comment: That's dependent on $x=c$.  Not on $y=x_0$ which is the point that they chose.  To prove that a function is continuous *at* a particular point $x = c$.  The $x=c$ is fixed.  You have to show that if you pick a variable unfixed $y$ somewhere so that $|y - x| <\delta$ that .... whatever.....  Because the \*$y$* is what you pick you can't have $\delta$ based on it.  But the \*$x$* is fixed and steady.  You *can* have $\delta$ based on $x=c$.  *That* one particular $x=c$.  For another value of $x=k$ you'd have a different $\delta$ based on a different value $k$.

Comment: " Isn't it okay then?"  Yes, and *that* delta will work.  And any delta smaller would work.  And that is not the largest possible choice of delta.  But it *is* an acceptable delta.   To my mind saying "therefore $\delta =$" sounds like you are saying delta *must* be that value.  It'd be more accurate to say "If we choose $\delta$ to be this value that will be *sufficient*".  ... but it's a minor point.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help (and sorry again for the typos at the beginning)! I am a statistics student, hence I do not have pure math lectures, so my more "formal proofs" often lack some minor details.  If you would write an answer I would check it, but you do not have to. :)

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/854739/118056) might be helpful.

Comment: That made things more clear. Thank you @IvoTerek

Comment: Why do you want to factor out $3$ at the beginning? It makes things so much more complicated.

Comment: @mrsamy In retrospect it really was not that smart. But the idea was to get to the point that I |x-y| by using the triangle inequality

Comment: @mrsamy I should have extracted |x-y| and then used the fact that |x|-|y| <= |x-y| < delta and there for.  |x| < 1 + |y| (delta). Then I can just solve it more easily but the delta is the same

Comment: @Bruno: then you could factor out $4$ instead of $3$ to avoid using fractions :-)

Comment: Yeah that is a good point, but it didn't bother me I don't know why haha.

Comment: @mrsamy Thank you again so much. I would not know what I would do without you ;-).

Comment: @Bruno: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks good. The following steps could be simplified a bit to make it more readable.

\begin{align}
\left\lvert f(x)-f(y) \right\rvert
&=
3\left\lvert \frac {4}{3}x^2 - \frac {4}{3}y^2 + x-y \right\rvert
\quad (\textrm{why bother factoring out $3$?})\\
& \le 3 \left(\left\lvert \frac {4}{3}x^2 - \frac {4}{3}y^2 \right\rvert + \left\lvert x-y \right\rvert \right)\\
& \le 3 \left(\frac {4}{3}\left\lvert x^2 - y^2 \right\rvert + \delta \right)
\quad (\color{red}{\textrm{for $|x-y|<\delta$} })\\
&= 3 \left(\frac {4}{3}\left\lvert (x - y) \right\rvert\left\lvert (x +y) \right\rvert + \delta \right)\\
&= 3 \left(\frac {4}{3}\left\lvert x - y + 2y \right\rvert \delta + \delta \right)\\
&\le 3 \left(\frac {4}{3}(\left\lvert x - y \right\rvert +\left\lvert 2y \right\rvert) \delta + \delta \right)
\quad (\textrm{triangle inequality})\\
&\le 3 \left(\frac {4}{3}(\delta +\left\lvert 2y \right\rvert) \delta + \delta \right)\\
&=4(\delta +\left\lvert 2y \right\rvert) \delta + 3\delta
\\
&\le 
4(1+\left\lvert 2y \right\rvert) \delta + 3\delta
\quad (\delta\le 1)\\
&\le (7+|8y|)\delta
\end{align}

Set $$\delta =\min(\frac {\epsilon}{\left\lvert 8y \right\rvert + 7} ,1).$$

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $f(x)=4 x^2 + 3 x + 17$ is continuous $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$

$$\underset{x\to a}{\text{lim}}\left(4 x^2+3 x+17\right)=f(a)$$
Equivalently
$$\underset{h\to 0}{\text{lim}}\left(4 (a+h)^2+3 (a+h)+17\right)=4 a^2 + 3 a + 17$$
$\forall \varepsilon>0$ we must find a $\delta>0$ such that if $|h|<\delta$ then
$$|4 (a+h)^2+3 (a+h)+17-(4 a^2 + 3 a + 17)|<\varepsilon$$
that is
$$|8 a h+4 h^2+3 h|<\varepsilon$$

$$0<\delta<\left|\frac{1}{8} \sqrt{64 a^2+48 a+16 e+9}+\frac38-a\right|$$
if $|h|<\delta$ then $|f(a+h)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$

Comment: Thanks for your post. But could you please verify if or if not my answer is correct. I know that there are different ways like yours but it doe not really help me.

Comment: Express $\delta$ as $ \frac {\varepsilon}{7}$. So you prove that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuos on any $[a,b]$

Comment: Why can I just leave out the $ (\left \vert 8y \right \vert )^{-1}$?