# Proving the function $f(x)=x^n$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

> I want to prove that given $y\in \mathbb R, n\in \mathbb N, \epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any $u\in\mathbb R$, $|u-y|<\delta$ implies $|u^n-y^n|<\epsilon$. It is not permitted to use any notion of product rule of limits, continuous function etc. Only a pure epsilon-delta argument has to be used.

**So here's my attempt:**

We proceed by induction. For $n=1$, clearly $\delta=\epsilon$. Assume the result true for all $k\le n-1$. Now fix $\epsilon>0$ and consider $|u^n-y^n|=|u-y||u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}y+\cdots +y^{n-1}|$. The term $|u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}y+\cdots +y^{n-1}|$ seems to be the issue. I need to bound this quantity in terms of $\epsilon$ by using the induction hypothesis. Now I am thinking of something like $|u^{n-j}|<\frac{\epsilon}{n}+|y^{n-j}|$ but cannot seem to get a coherent argument.

Comment: maybe this helps? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2365076/532409

Comment: just to be clear: when I say "maybe it helps" I mean that it is seems a duplicate..  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|y-x|<1$, then $|y|=|y-x+x|\leqslant|x|+1$. Therefore\begin{align}|x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots+y^{n-1}|&\leqslant|x|^{n-1}+|x|^{n-2}\bigl(|x|+1\bigr)+\cdots+\bigl(|x|+1\bigr)^{n-1}\\&\leqslant n\bigl(|x|+1\bigr)^{n-1}.\end{align}So, take$$\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon{n\bigl(|x|+1\bigr)^{n-1}}\right\}.$$

Comment: In your first line we may as well write $|y|<|x|+1$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Also, this is not a proof by induction. Right?

Comment: That is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Let's take a specific example, say $n=2$. You need to argue, given $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $\left|y^2-u^2\right| < \epsilon$ for all $u \in (y-\delta,y+\delta)$.

So if $u \in (y-\delta,y+\delta)$, then we have
$$
\left|y^2-u^2\right| = |u-y||u+y| \le \delta (2y+\delta)
$$
and so you need to pick $\delta$ so that $\delta (2y+\delta) < \epsilon$.